# how to swap queues in java when they have different number of elements?

Tags: java

how can we swap two queues in java with constant time complexity?
I thought of trying this out.
Is it possible to write:

```
temp=q1;
q1=q2;
q2=temp;
```

here q1 ,q2 and q3 are linkedlist based queues.

Comment: Your logic looks good. What is wrong with it ?

Comment: I just want to ask is it possible or not?

Comment: Why don't you just give a shot and check ?

Comment: The code you have shown is perfect to swap the `Queue`s in constant time. The swap operation you have shown just swaps reference of both queues therefore it doesn't swap all elements (which has `O(n)` complexity) and it swaps the references in `O(1)` constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to swap two queues in constant time. If queues are of size n then it will take O(n) time to swap elements of one queue into another. However you can change front and rear of both queues which will take O(1) i.e. constant time.

Comment: Please give reason for down voting. So that i know my mistake if there is any.

Comment: This is wrong. The question's own code does it in constant time.

Comment: From code snippet nothing was clear. That's why i posted this answer. Code is ambiguous.If complete method with declaration of Collection being used was posted, i would have given different answer.